# Proof that $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}{k \choose m} = {n \choose m}2^{n-m}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Can someone suggest a proof using generating functions? if possible

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}{k \choose m} = {n \choose m}2^{n-m} $$

Moreover, do both sides of the equation count the number of subsets of $n-m$ elements out of $n$ elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the sides count is a bit more complicated than "The number of subsets of $n-m$ elements". First note that because of the $\binom{k}{m}$, the sum on the left side might as well be $\sum_{k = m}^n$. From there the combinatorial argument goes a bit like this:

Right hand side: Out of $n$ (distinguishable) balls, pick $m$ of them and set aside. With the rest, paint each one either red or blue.

Left hand side: Out of $n$ balls, pick $k$ to put aside, and paint the rest blue. Now from the $k$ balls put aside, pick $m$, put *them* aside, and paint the rest red.

All in all, what they count is the number of ways to pick out $m$ balls that are not painted, and then paint the rest of the balls either red or blue.

Comment: brilliant thanks!!!, may i accept two answers for this question. I would like to see another solution.

Comment: It's not technically possible to tick more than one answer as "accepted"; the site won't let you. However, you're free to upvote any answer you like.

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked for a proof using generating functions, then you may consider that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \left( {1 + \left( {1 + x} \right)} \right)^{\,n}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_j {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)2^{\,n - j} x^{\,j} }  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_k {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_j {\left( {\sum\limits_k {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  k \\ 
  j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} } \right)x^{\,j} }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

I’ll give first a combinatorial argument, since that shows most clearly what is being counted. As usual $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. $\binom{n}k\binom{k}m$ is the number of ways to choose a set $S\subseteq[n]$ of cardinality $k$ and then choose an $m$-element subset $M$ of $S$; the result is to divide $[n]$ into the pairwise disjoint sets $M,S\setminus M$, and $[n]\setminus S$. Summing over $k$ gives us the number of ways to divide $[n]$ into pairwise disjoint sets $M,A$, and $B$ such that $|M|=m$. We can count the same thing by observing that there are $\binom{n}m$ ways to choose $M$, after which we can choose any one of the $2^{n-m}$ subsets of $[n]\setminus M$ to be $A$; this can be done in $\binom{n}m2^{n-m}$ ways.

An algebraic argument is very straightforward:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{k}m&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}m\binom{n-m}k\\
&=\binom{n}m\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-m}k\\
&=\binom{n}m2^{n-m}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Using generating functions seems a bit clumsy here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. may I ask how is the first move in the algebric proof is straighforward. (switching index such that n above m will appear )

Comment: @Tom: The identity $\binom{n}k\binom{k}m=\binom{n}m\binom{n-m}k$ is a pretty standard one. It’s easily proved if you expand the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials. It also has an easy combinatorial proof similar to the one for the whole result: $\binom{n}k\binom{k}m$ counts splits $M,A,B$ with $|M|=m$ and $|M\cup A|=k$ by splitting off $M\cup A$ first and then $M$, while $\binom{n}m\binom{n-m}k$ does it by first splitting off $M$ and then splitting off $A$ from what remains.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation based upon the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
 \begin{align*}
 [z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
 \end{align*}

> We obtain for $n\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
>  \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m}
>  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty[z^k](1+z)^n[u^m](1+u)^k\tag{1}\\
>  &=[u^m]\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1+u)^k[z^k](1+z)^n\tag{2}\\
>  &=[u^m](2+u)^n\tag{3}\\
>  &=[u^m]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}z^k2^{n-k}\tag{4}\\
>  &=\binom{n}{m}2^{n-m}\tag{5}
>  \end{align*}
>    and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and set the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (3) we use the substitution rule with $z:=1+u$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k u^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k [z^k]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we expand the binomial.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $u^m$.